# Trouble getting started with maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm sorry to sound ignorant here, but I'm new to Maven, and have been banging my head against something that I'm sure is quite simple.

The [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_assembly) say:

> [...] a project could produce a ZIP assembly which contains a project's JAR artifact in the root directory, the runtime dependencies in a lib/ directory, and a shell script to launch a stand-alone application.

which is **exactly** what I want to do! But I can't seem to make it happen.

My POM is as follows:

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.anearalone</groupId>
   <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   [...]
   <build>
      <finalName>myapp</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.1</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>make-assembly</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <descriptors>
                     <descriptor>src/main/assemble/dist.xml</descriptor>
                  </descriptors>
                  <archive>
                     <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.anearalone.myapp.CLI</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                     </manifest>
                  </archive>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
[...]
</project>
```

and the referenced dist.xml looks like this:

```
<assembly>
   <id>dist</id>
   <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
   </formats>
   <files>
      <file>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
         <source>src/main/bin/arkify.sh</source>
         <fileMode>755</fileMode>
      </file>
   </files>
   <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
         <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <includes>
             <include>*:jar</include>
          </includes>
          <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
      </dependencySet>
      <dependencySet>
         <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
         <includes>
            <include>com.anearalone:myapp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</include>
         </includes>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      </dependencySet>
   </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This achieves the layout I want in the zip file (though I'm quite sure I'm not getting there in the correct way) but I get two jars in `target/` (one in the zip archive, the other in the root), and neither of them includes my mainClass entry in the resultant `MANIFEST.MF`.

If I change the `project.packaging` to "pom", which I thought might be correct, of course the extra jar (in the root of `target/` goes away, but I get these warning:

```
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.anearalone:myapp:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
o  'com.anearalone:myapp'
```

... and indeed my artifact is not in the archive, and there are still no entries added to `MANIFEST.MF`.

Anyone have time to help out a beginner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your ZIP is correctly created, but the `my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` contained in it (as well as the JAR directly located in `target/` directory) does not include your main class in the `MANIFEST.MF` file?

In fact, the `assembly` plugin is not dedicated to execute such a task. This is the task of the [JAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), which provides a way to indicates, in the `MANIFEST.MF` [the main class of your project](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make). You simply must **add** this configuration in your current `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>my.app.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

---

Regarding your try to change the packaging of the project to a `pom` packaging: it was a bad idea ;) Indeed, the `pom` packaging is used for project without any other resources than the `pom.xml` itself. It is really useful for `pom.xml` that are defined as [the parent of others projects](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance), or to [aggregate multiples modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation).

Comment: Ah, perfect! I should have inferred this from the first couple of lines on the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html). Thanks very much!