# Maven Warnings with building a multi-module aggregate assembly project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

Running mvn package from the target directory of my parent project, it looks like my application is building correctly but I do not know what these warnings are telling me.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Vapor Runtime 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) @ vapor-runtime ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/assemble/assembly.xml
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[INFO] Copying files to C:\Users\pdl\Projects\Vapor-Head\08_Source_Code\vapor\runtime\target\vapor
[WARNING] Assembly file: C:\Users\pdl\Projects\Vapor-Head\08_Source_Code\vapor\runtime\target\vapor is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[INFO] Building zip: C:\Users\pdl\Projects\Vapor-Head\08_Source_Code\vapor\runtime\target\vapor.zip
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.b3l:vapor-runtime:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[INFO] Building tar: C:\Users\pdl\Projects\Vapor-Head\08_Source_Code\vapor\runtime\target\vapor.tar.gz
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Vapor .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Vapor Correlation .................................. SUCCESS [  0.733 s]
[INFO] Vapor Fusion ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.026 s]
[INFO] Vapor Core ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.094 s]
[INFO] Vapor Prioritization ............................... SUCCESS [  0.022 s]
[INFO] Vapor Runtime ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.584 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.549 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-14T09:31:42-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then when I try to run the application, it fails with this message:

```
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\Vapor-Head\08_Source_Code\vapor\runtime\target>java -javaagent:bin/bigio-agent-1.2.jar -Dio.bigio.components=io.bigio.cli.CommandLineInterface,com.b3l.vapor.core.Vapor -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -cp "bin/bigio-core-1.2.jar;config;lib/*;components/*" io.bigio.BigIO
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : bin/bigio-agent-1.2.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I must not have my assembly or pom files set up correctly.  **I can provide any additional information necessary** but can anyone guess what the issue is by these messages?

**EDIT:**

Including assembly:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>runtime</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
        <format>zip</format>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <includes>
                <include>io.bigio:bigio-runtime:zip:1.2</include>
            </includes>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>bigio/lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>com.b3l:utilities</include>
                <include>com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml</include>
                <include>log4j:log4j</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>bigio/components</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>com.b3l:vapor-core</include>
                <include>com.b3l:vapor-correlation</include>
                <include>com.b3l:vapor-fusion</include>
                <include>com.b3l:vapor-prioritization</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bigio/config</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>scripts</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bigio</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bigio/outputs</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This is the POM file for the parent project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Vapor\pom -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.b3l</groupId>
    <artifactId>vapor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>Vapor Parent Module</description>
    <name>Vapor</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <version.bigio>1.2</version.bigio>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>correlation</module>
        <module>fusion</module>
        <module>runtime</module>
        <module>prioritization</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>com.b3l.vapor.core.Vapor</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.bigio</groupId>
                <artifactId>bigio-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.bigio}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.bigio</groupId>
                <artifactId>bigio-agent</artifactId>
                <version>${version.bigio}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.bigio</groupId>
                <artifactId>bigio-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>${version.bigio}</version>
                <type>zip</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.b3l</groupId>
                <artifactId>utilities</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Additional Information:**

To make things really confusing, BigIO is packaged as an aggregate assembly project.  The instructions for how to use BigIO is to build your/my application as an aggregate assembly project and include my jars for all child projects into BigIO's components folder.

**BigIO's assembly.xml file:**

It contains a dir format and works for the BigIO project.  We also have another application that uses a dir format.  I've been trying to use our existing configurations as a template (if you will) to help me set up this one.  But I'm having a real difficult time getting it to work.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>runtime</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
        <format>zip</format>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <fileMode>0664</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0777</directoryMode>
            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>io.bigio:bigio-core</include>
                <include>io.bigio:bigio-agent</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>io.bigio:bigio-runtime</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <fileMode>0664</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0777</directoryMode>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>io.bigio:bigio-core</exclude>
                <exclude>io.bigio:bigio-agent</exclude>
                <exclude>io.bigio:bigio-runtime</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <fileMode>0664</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0777</directoryMode>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/logs</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <fileMode>0664</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0777</directoryMode>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/components</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <fileMode>0664</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0777</directoryMode>
            <directory>config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/config</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>run.bat</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>run.sh</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>config/logback.xml</source>
            <outputDirectory>/config</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

In case you're interested, here is the [BigIO project](https://github.com/Archarithms/bigio).

**We had a guy working with us who used the maven-assembly-plugin to package all dependencies. *He has since left the company* and I'm trying to figure out how he did this. I am just now learning about the maven-assembly-plugin.**

Comment: Can you provide `assembly.xml` ? And `maven-assembly-plugin` custom configuration (if any).

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711281/trouble-getting-started-with-maven-assembly-plugin), it might help

Comment: [Or this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276453/maven-assembly-include-the-current-project-jar-in-the-final-zip-tar)

Comment: @LoganMzz -  I've added my parent project's POM file and the assembly.xml file.  See the end of my question for more information.

Comment: Creating a assembly descriptor which has the format `dir`  will never work this way..and will always produce warnings...

Comment: @khmarbaise - I'm glad to see your comment, as I know you know this topic very well.  I'm using the other assembly files and projects as my example for mine.  The other projects I am working with have a dir format.  I am new to this, so please forgive my ignorance.  what exactly does the dir format do?

Comment: The `dir` format will create a folder in `target` folder..The problem which arises with this is that maven-assembly-plugin will try to attach all artifacts which are being created via descriptors to the project and will try to upload them to a repository. The problem with a `dir` format is simple, cause it can't be attached, cause this would result in many attachments..which do not have classifiers etc.. If you like having a `dir` format you need to make a separate execution of maven-assembly-plugin and configure `attach to false`.

Comment: Apart from that i don't understand why you need the `dir` format?

Comment: @khmarbaise - There is an entire section in our other assembly project that includes our repository.  I didn't know why, so I deleted it from mine.  Maybe if I add that section back in then it will work.  I have to get this project to run ASAP and there is nobody else here who knows how to build these assembly projects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92291/discussion-between-miss-lucy-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: There's just too much code here. Try to reduce it to a simple example, otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: @Tunaki - I managed to get the multi-module problem solved.  But now I'm having trouble creating an assembly with a single-module project.  Please see my question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33176084/1735836